# Interactive plotly figure is flickering when text is added

Tags: r, plotly

I'm trying to make an interactive plotly figure (using plotly for R) where each frame is a histogram. On top of each frame, I want to write some text. The following minimal example illustrates what I want to achieve.

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

dat <- tibble(x = rnorm(10000,0,1), f = rep(1:10, each = 1000))
dat2 <- tibble(x = -3, y = 70, f = seq(1,10), txt = paste0("frame ", seq(1,10)))

plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(data = dat,
            x = ~x,
            frame = ~f,
            type = "histogram",
            showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  add_trace(data = dat2,
            x = ~x,
            y = ~y,
            frame = ~f,
            type = "scatter",
            mode = "text",
            text = ~txt,
            showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  animation_opts(
    transition = 0,
    frame = 100,
  ) %>%
  config(staticPlot = TRUE)
```

The issue here is that, when I add text on top of each frame, the animation starts to flicker. The flickering isn't there if I remove the second `add_trace`. Any idea why this is happening and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `add_annotations` instead of `add_trace`. You could slightly adapt the code written by @kat [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72176553/plotly-r-how-to-add-dynamic-annotation-which-belongs-to-frame) to make sure the text is smoothly shown in each frame of the plot. In this case, you have to make sure that the iteration of each frame takes the input of your annotation dataframe. Here is some reproducible code:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

dat <- tibble(x = rnorm(10000,0,1), f = rep(1:10, each = 1000))
dat2 <- tibble(x = -3, y = 70, f = seq(1,10), txt = paste0("frame ", seq(1,10)))

p1 <- plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(data = dat,
            x = ~x,
            frame = ~f,
            type = "histogram",
            showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  animation_opts(
    transition = 0,
    frame = 100
  ) %>%
  config(staticPlot = TRUE)

p2 <- plotly_build(p1)

lapply(1:nrow(dat2), 
       function(i){
         annotation = list(
           type = "text",
           x = dat2[i,]$x,
           y = dat2[i,]$y,
           xref = "x",
           yref = "y",
           showarrow = F,
           text = dat2[i, ]$txt) 
         p2$x$frames[[i]]$layout <<- list(annotations = list(annotation)) 
       })

p2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up doing this but I was still annoyed about the flickering, so I thought I'd ask about it. About this solution though. Why isn't the annotation on the first frame loaded before you hit Play (or move the slider)? You can get around it by adding `layout(annotations = list(x = -3, y = 70, text = "frame 1", showarrow = FALSE))` to the definition of `p1` but that seems a bit awkward having to do.